# `go test` file modification monitoring for automated testing

Tags: unit-testing, go, automated-tests

Is there a way to have `go test` run whenever a project's files are modified?

Perhaps there is a good general solution to run a command when files in a path are modified that could be used for this use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) for that. Example watching some dir and executing `go test` on close while having data written:

```
inotifywait -e close_write <dir> | while read file; do go test; done
```

Or you write your own tool in go utilizing the [`howeyc/fsnotify`](https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify) package: [Similar example application](https://github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon).

There's also [rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun), written in ruby:

```
rerun go test
```

Above command will watch the current directory for changes and run `go test` when a change occurs.

Comment: Great list of options. I'll add http://entrproject.org/ to the mix as it looks simple, effective and easy to use.

Comment: fsnotify is good (GoConvey used to use it) but we ran into "too many open files" errors. If you run into that problem, you may consider a tool like [GoConvey](http://smartystreets.github.io/goconvey) which will run tests automatically, you can view them in the browser, and won't open all the files constantly to watch them.